# Children component not refresh with new prop

Tags: reactjs

I have parent component with these code:

```
<div>
 {widgetList.map((widget,index,array) => {
            const zIndex = array.length - index;
            return(
              <div key={widget._id} style={{zIndex}}>
                <RenderWidget 
                  widget={widget} 
                  index={index} 
                  array={array} 
                  dataWidgetRead={dataWidgetRead} 
                  widgetValues={widgetValues} 
                  rofileType={props.profileType} 
                  handleOpenProfileWidget={handleOpenProfileWidget} 
                  isResizable={isResizable} 
                  setWidgetValues={setDataFromWidget}/>
                </div>
            )
          } )}
</div>
```

RenderWidget returns a component depends "widget.type".

All of params that I write on `RenderWidget` are states. WidgetValues is an object that receive new params via socket. I need when WidgetValues changes, the component that i rendered with renderWidget function, do re-render, but it doesnt happen.

Anyone know why?

---

RENDER FUNCTION:

```
  const RenderWidget = (props) => {
    const { widget, index, array, dataWidgetRead, widgetValues, profileType, handleOpenProfileWidget, isResizable, setWidgetValues } = props;
    const actions = <WidgetMenuButton />
    if (
      widget.widgetType === 'TEXT' ||
      widget.widgetType === 'MAP' ||
      widget.widgetType === 'HTML' ||
      (dataWidgetRead && widget.connectedDevices[0].historicaldata)
    ) {
      let connectedDevice;
      let attributes;
      let historicalData;
      let data;

      const actions = (
        <WidgetMenuButton
          widget={widget}
          profileType={profileType}
          entity={'widget'}
          clickView={handleOpenProfileWidget}
        />
      );
      switch (widget.widgetType) {
        case 'BARS':
          if (widgetValues[widget._id] === undefined) {
            data = formatToDataBarwidget(widget.connectedDevices);
            setWidgetValues(widget._id, data);
          }
          if(!widgetValues[widget._id]){
            return null
          }else{
          return (
            <>
              <WidgetCard
                className="d-block"
                title={widget.name}
                actions={actions}
              >
                <BarChart
                  height={'100%'}
                  details={widgetValues[widget._id]}
                  title={widget.name}
                  actions={actions}
                  axisBottomText={widget.configurationWidget['label-x']}
                  axisLeftText={widget.configurationWidget['label-y']}
                  orientation={widget.configurationWidget.orientation}
                />
              </WidgetCard>
            </>
          );
          }

        case 'LINES':
          if (widgetValues[widget._id] === undefined) {
            data = formatToDataLinewidget(widget.connectedDevices, widget.configurationWidget);

            data.legendX = widget.configurationWidget['label-x']
              ? widget.configurationWidget['label-x']
              : 'Fecha';
            data.legendY = widget.configurationWidget['label-y']
              ? widget.configurationWidget['label-y']
              : 'Valor';
              setWidgetValues(widget._id, data);
          }
          if(!widgetValues[widget._id]){
            return null
          }else{
            return (
                <WidgetLineApexChart
                  title={widget.name}
                  actions={actions}
                  details={widgetValues[widget._id]}
                  id={widget._id}
                />
            );
          }

        case 'INVALID':
          return (
              <WidgetCard title={widget.name} actions={actions}>
                No ha sido posible cargar los datos del dispositivo, compruebe
                la configuración e inténtelo de nuevo.
              </WidgetCard>
          );

        default:
          return (
              <WidgetCard title={widget.name} actions={actions}>
                No ha sido posible cargar los datos del dispositivo, compruebe
                la configuración e inténtelo de nuevo.
              </WidgetCard>
          );
      }
    } else {
      return (
          <WidgetCard title={widget.name} actions={actions}>
            No ha sido posible cargar los datos del dispositivo, compruebe la
            configuración e inténtelo de nuevo.
          </WidgetCard>
      );
    }
}
```

And the function that i receive from socket:

```
const getAttributesByWebSocket = message => {
    if(message[0] === '{'){
      try {
        const messageDecoded = JSON.parse(message);
        const toUpdate = getWidgetToUpdate(messageDecoded);
        const newValues = refreshWidgetData(toUpdate, messageDecoded, widgetValues);
        setWidgetValues(newValues);
      } catch (e) {
        return console.log('Bad Response: ', e);
      }
    }
    return true;
  }
```

if i change `newValues` from this function with an string, for example, provocate new render, but with an object with new values, no..

Comment: The code you've shown is insufficient to answer the question. Please also show us the `RenderWidget` component and how you update the `widgetList`.

Comment: Done! in each case, i call "SetWidgetValues". this function set new state on parent component

Comment: But that does not show how you actually update `widgetList` when receiving new data via socket which will trigger the re-render. Also you should not trigger a state update during render except for rare use cases. The way to go here would be to construct a new `widgetList` and update the state directly in the parent.

Answer (score 0):

You'd use `RenderWidget` as a component and not as a function:

```
<div>
 {widgetList.map((widget,index,array) => <RenderWidget widget={widget} index={index} array={array} dataWidgetRead={dataWidgetRead} widgetValues={widgetValues} profileType={props.profileType}, handleOpenProfileWidget={handleOpenProfileWidget} isResizable={isResizable} setDataFromWidget={setDataFromWidget} />)}
</div>

const RenderWidget = ({widget, index, array, dataWidgetRead, widgetValues, profileType, handleOpenProfileWidget, isResizable, setDataFromWidget}) => {
```

To make it simpler you can also collect the props into one `props` object.

Comment: I just do this. Im going to edit the post with new code. It doesnt update :/

Comment: if an object value change, might provocate new render or not?

Comment: Im testing, changing value receive from socket, and it provocate render, but with new values, no.... what's happening?!